# When binding a event to two functions and unbinding it inside one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When binding a event to two functions and unbinding it inside one function.

Are both functions guaranteed to be triggered by the event? 
Or should it happen that the function with the unbind event is called first and the event is unbinding both functions and the second function never gets called?

I made a fiddle and it looks like both functions get called only once, which is exactly what I need, but is it guaranteed to always be that way? http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/8qsdk2tg/

Is there a way to only unbind the the currently executing function from an event? So that each function unbinds itself?

```
$('div').bind('click',function(){
    $('div').unbind('click');
    $('body').append('Fired First Bind Event!<br/>');
});
$('div').bind('click',function(){
    $('body').append('Fired Second Bind Event!<br/>');    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will fire, as the event will continue to propogate to other clicks already set on the item.  If you then click the item again, neither will fire, as they have both been unset.

Comment: So it is save to assume both function will fire once and only once with this code?

Comment: Indeed, thought you could suppress the second one by firing `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but I had to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('div').bind('click', first);
$('div').bind('click', second);

function first() {
    $('div').unbind('click', first);
    $('body').append('Fired First Bind Event!<br/>');
}

function second() {
    $('body').append('Fired Second Bind Event!<br/>');    
}
```

This will unbind only the `first` function.

Comment: Nice! This might actually be a better solution in terms of readability and coupling(Say there was a third function bound to that event, which should not be unbound!).